# Why wp_update_post() does not update GUID?

Tags: wp-update-post

Trying to update `GUID` on a attachment using the `wp_update_post()` function but its not updating GUID nor its throwing any error.

Example code:

```php
$post = [
    'ID'   => 45,
    'guid' => 'https://example.com/foo.png'
];
    
wp_update_post($post);
```

Comment: Why need to update guid?

Comment: I'm not updating GUID for actual post but for attachment. I am planning to serve images from a image hosting site rather than serving from me. It works fine but I need to update GUID for that.

Comment: Why? You are aware that the GUID has nothing to do with the post's permalink, right? It's just an identifier. Changing the GUID won't change a post's URL.

Comment: I am not changing post permalink. It's for different thing. Anyway I figured it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out WordPress do not recommend updating `GUID` thus its disallowed.

But we can update it using sql query:

```php
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->update($wpdb->posts, ['guid' => $newGUID], ['ID' => $postID]);
```

Comment: I'm sure it would have been intentionally disallowed to prevent changes to it, while it's fine for attachments, preventing changing it in most cases was probably a good idea given it's not supposed to change.

Comment: Yes. changing GUID is not wordpress recommends. But sometimes it has/needs to be changed.